# how to use string_agg in sequlaize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

How can I use below code in sequalize.js node js

```
SELECT 
STRING_AGG( firstname , '-' )  AS name

From student
```

I am getting error when I am using below code.

getting error as :

```
{
    "message": "STRING_AGG is not defined",
    "error": {}
}
```

need some help

```
var query = {
attributes:[
[sequelize.fn(STRING_AGG( sequelize.col('firstname') , '-' ) ) , name]]
 }

db['student'].findAll(query).then(function (names) {
 callback(null, names);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I got the solution to do it.

```
var query = {
attributes:[
[sequelize.literal("STRING_AGG(firstname,'-')"), 'name']]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

sequelize.fn takes the function name as a string in the first parameter.

So where you wrote

`[sequelize.fn(STRING_AGG( sequelize.col('firstname') , '-' ) ) , name]`

should actually be

`[sequelize.fn('STRING_AGG', sequelize.col('firstname') , '-' ) , name]`